# Problem with permissions when configuring an API Gateway REST API through Terraform

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway, cicd

I am deploying an AWS API Gateway API using Terraform.
The API Gateway has multiple endpoints and is backed by a single Lambda (through Lambda Proxy Integration).

Even though in my Terraform script I gave permission to API Gateway to Invoke the lambda function, invoking the API endpoints yields an HTTP 403 error.
And for each endpoint, I have to go within the API Gateway console and **Add Permission to Lambda Function** (i.e. setting the re-selecting the Lambda Function through editing the Integration Request within the Resource, and then clicking OK on the 'Add Permission to Lambda Function' Dialog that shows up).

Here is the Terraform snippet I use to give API Gateway the permissions to invoke my Lambda.

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "api_gw" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.theapilambda.function_name
  qualifier     = aws_lambda_alias.devo_lambda_alias.name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyApi.execution_arn}/*"
}
```

I have experimented with the source_arn (using `/*/*/*` or `/*/*` instead of `/*`) but this didn't work (same problem)

Is it even possible to have a single permission assignment statement in Terraform, or do I need one for every single endpoint exposed by the API?

Comment: Does that help you?
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-403-error-lambda-authorizer

Do you have an explicit deny somewhere in your policies?

Comment: Does it work if you change your `source_arn` from `"${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyApi.execution_arn}/*"` to `"${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyApi.execution_arn}/*/*/*"` ?
?

Comment: @tonystrawberry, there is no explicit deny anywhere in the policies

Comment: @tonystrawberry, I had tried "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyApi.execution_arn}/*/*/*"

It's one of the things I tried; my original post was faulty (I'm editing it)

Comment: @tonystrawberry there is no authorizer involved so the article you posted does not apply here

Comment: I have `"${aws_apigatewayv2_api.main.execution_arn}/*/*/*"` (literally copied from real config), and it works. You specify an alias (`aws_lambda_alias.devo_lambda_alias.name`) - are you endpoints actually using this alias as well? If they use another alias (or function directly), this permission will not work.

Comment: @STerliakov, removing the qualifier worked partially. Thank you for that. 
Now, the policy statement appears in the Lambda console, and many of the API endpoints work.
However, some of them still fail with an HTTP 500: those are the APIs in the form `GET /segment1/segment2/{path parameter}` ; do you have a tip about that?

Comment: Out of scope, but I'd suggest that you point API endpoints to aliases instead of removing qualifier here - it'll be good for CI/CD pipeline you'll build at some point. CodeDeploy changes version to which an alias points, allowing for safe deployments of new code versions which can be revertedin 1 click or automatically with a hook.

Comment: If some still fail with 500 - check that a) they are failing not on the lambda level (you can find it out by checking CloudWatch logs for relevant lambda), b) are actually called by apigateway (see ApiGateway logs), and c) these endpoints are also using function directly without alias. If some use function and some - alias, you'll need separate permission both for function and for alias.